# how to display the faculty name and subject of students he/she enrolled

Tags: php, mysql

how can I display only the faculty name and subject of students he/she enrolled in my evaluation form

here's my table structure

```
Table Name: student_list

| Column Name | Data Type   |
|-------------|-------------|
| id          | INT         |
| school_id   | INT         |
| email       | VARCHAR(255)|
| Fname       | VARCHAR(50) |
| Mname       | VARCHAR(50) |
| Lname       | VARCHAR(50) |
| class_id    | INT         |
| password    | VARCHAR(255)|
```

```
Table Name: faculty_list

| Column Name | Data Type   |
|-------------|-------------|
| id          | INT         |
| school_id   | INT         |
| Fname       | VARCHAR(50) |
| Mname       | VARCHAR(50) |
| Lname       | VARCHAR(50) |
| college     | VARCHAR(100)|
```

```
Table Name: restriction_list

| Column Name | Data Type   |
|-------------|-------------|
| id          | INT         |
| order_by    | INT         |
| faculty_id  | INT         |
| class_id    | INT         |
| subject_id  | INT         |
```

```
Table Name: class_list

| Column Name          | Data Type   |
|----------------------|-------------|
| id                   | INT         |
| faculty_id           | INT         |
| college              | VARCHAR(100)|
| course               | VARCHAR(100)|
| year_level           | INT         |
| section              | VARCHAR(20) |
| subject_code         | VARCHAR(20) |
| subject_description  | VARCHAR(255)|
```

In the restriction table I will select the faculty name, class, and subject of students in the drop down menu

my php in evaluaiton form

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require './config.php';//database connection

  //prevent access without log in
  if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim ($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {
    header('location: student.php');
    exit();

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `student_list` WHERE school_id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  }

  $rid='';
$faculty_id='';
$subject_id='';
if(isset($_GET['rid']))
$rid = $_GET['rid'];
if(isset($_GET['fid']))
$faculty_id = $_GET['fid'];
if(isset($_GET['sid']))
$subject_id = $_GET['sid'];

$restriction = $db->query("SELECT r.id,s.id as sid,f.id as fid,concat(f.Lname,' ',f.Fname,' ',f.Mname) as faculty,s.subject,s.description FROM restriction_list r inner join faculty_list f on f.id = r.faculty_id inner join class_list s on s.id = r.subject_id and r.id not in (SELECT restriction_id from evaluation_list)");
?>
```

```
<h1 class="app-page-title">Select Faculty</h1>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="list-group">
          <?php 
            while($row=$restriction->fetch_array()):
              if(empty($rid)){
                  $rid = $row['id'];
                  $faculty_id = $row['fid'];
                  $subject_id = $row['sid'];
                }
              ?>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action <?php echo isset($rid) && $rid == $row['id'] ? 'active' : '' ?>" href="student-evaluate.php?&rid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&sid=<?php echo $row['sid'];?>&fid=<?php echo $row['fid'];?>"><?php echo ucwords($row['faculty']).' -  '.$row['subject'].' '.$row['description'] ?></a>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm expecting to display only the faculty name and subjects of students he/she enrolled in evaluation form

Comment: Is it correct that each student can only be in one class? I'd have expected a separate table linking classes and students, so that multiple students can be in multiple classes. I don't know your specific use case, of course.

Comment: Aren't you already having both faculty and subject info in restriction_list?

Comment: the class_list, I use it to display the list of faculties, colleges, courses, year_levels, sections, and subjects.

Comment: Yes, when I select the faculty, class, and subject in the drop-down menu, it will add them to the restriction list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the PHP code to execute an SQL query that joins the `faculty`, `class`, and `restriction` tables, listing `faculty names` alongside their teaching subjects, while excluding combinations already present in the evaluation list. Check this

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require './config.php'; //database connection
    
    //prevent access without log in
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {
        header('location: student.php');
        exit();
    }
    
    $rid = '';
    $faculty_id = '';
    $subject_id = '';
    if (isset($_GET['rid'])) {
        $rid = $_GET['rid'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['fid'])) {
        $faculty_id = $_GET['fid'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['sid'])) {
        $subject_id = $_GET['sid'];
    }
    
    $student_id = $_SESSION['student_id']; // Assuming student_id is stored in the session

// Update your query
$query = "SELECT r.id, s.id AS sid, f.id AS fid, 
                 CONCAT(f.Lname, ' ', f.Fname, ' ', f.Mname) AS faculty, 
                 s.subject_code, s.subject_description 
          FROM restriction_list r 
          INNER JOIN faculty_list f ON f.id = r.faculty_id 
          INNER JOIN class_list s ON s.id = r.class_id
          INNER JOIN student_subjects ss ON ss.subject_id = s.id
          WHERE r.id NOT IN (SELECT restriction_id FROM evaluation_list)
          AND ss.student_id = '$student_id'";

    
    $restriction = $db->query($query);
    ?>
    
    <h1 class="app-page-title">Select Faculty</h1>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="list-group">
        <?php while ($row = $restriction->fetch_array()): ?>
            <?php 
                if (empty($rid)) {
                    $rid = $row['id'];
                    $faculty_id = $row['fid'];
                    $subject_id = $row['sid'];
                }
            ?>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action <?php echo isset($rid) && $rid == $row['id'] ? 'active' : '' ?>" 
               href="student-evaluate.php?rid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&sid=<?php echo $row['sid']; ?>&fid=<?php echo $row['fid']; ?>">
               <?php echo ucwords($row['faculty']) . ' - ' . $row['subject_code'] . ' ' . $row['subject_description']; ?>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How to do it if the student don't have a subject in the faculty; it won't show up in his or her evaluation form.

Comment: It is still displaying the faculty and subject even if the student hasn't enrolled in the faculty and subject.